# Editing an existing .txt file by exporting data from R

Tags: r, output, winbugs, openbugs

I'm creating some simulated disease count data for spatial modeling in OpenBUGS via the `BRugs` package in R.

I have an existing `.txt` file which contains most of the information I need to run my models in `BRugs`. Here's what this text file looks like:

```
list(N = 44,
   O = c(4, 8, 3, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2, 10, 13, 5, 7, 9, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 19, 7, 5, 4, 
        9, 2, 4, 6, 14, 13, 6, 7, 9, 3, 4, 10, 10, 8, 23, 24, 18, 10, 6, 4, 17, 7), 
   E = c(7.20902956, 7.81436792, 3.46693788, 7.04393728, 7.37412184, 
        4.45749156, 6.3285374, 4.45749156, 6.3285374, 6.76878348, 9,...)
   etc....
    ),
    sumNumNeigh = 212
    )
```

What I'd like to accomplish is to replace the `O` vector in the above `.txt` file with the `m` simulated disease count vectors than I generated in R. This way, I can have `m` new .txt files to use with `BRugs` to run my models.

For instance, let's say this new disease count vector is called `O_sim`:

```
 [1]  6  4  6  9  9  6 11  6  7  6 11  9  7 10  9 10  9  3 10  4  6  8  8  4  6  9  8  6  9  8  7  8  5 10  8  6  4  4  5  5  8
[42] 10  8 11
```

How could I go about created a new .txt file that now looks like this:

```
 list(N = 44,
    O = c(6,4,6,9,9,6,11,6,7,6,11,9,  
          7,10,9,10,9,3,10,4,6,8,8,4,6,
          9,8,6,9,8,7,8,5,10,8,6,4,4,5,5,
          8,10,8,11), 
    E = c(7.20902956, 7.81436792, 3.46693788, 7.04393728, 7.37412184, 
           etc...
         ),
    sumNumNeigh = 212
    )
```

Comment: Maybe `writeLines(deparse(myList), con="temp.txt")`?

Comment: @Imo, this almost does what I want. However, I actually have a list within a list, and this code doesn't preserve the dimensions of the objects within this sublist. That's why I'm interested in replaced only the 'O' vector of the existing text file.